# Postgres Upgrade Interrupted, pg_version now inconsistent

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

Recently attempted an upgrade from 9.3 to 9.4 on an Ubuntu 14.04 Postgres installation, something went awry and the system lost power midway through the upgrade. Now the cluster won't start and when I try to move the data file to a new system and start it, there are inconsistencies in the data files and PG_VERSIONs are varied between 9.3 and 9.4.

Is there any way to recover and make consistent the files to launch under a new cluster?

Comment: What was the steps you are doing until the power lost?

Comment: I was performing an `apt-get install postgresql-9.4`. I still have all the data files and when I look in the base folder and the various subfolders, a few have a PG_VERSION of 9.4 and most are still 9.3.

Comment: what I can suggest is 1. backup all the data folder,  2. run `sudo apt-get install -f` 3. `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4`

Comment: I have attempted this as well as reinstalling 9.3. The cluster won't start due to an error _DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.0_. When I switch to 9.3 it says the same thing except that it was initialized with 9.4 and not compatible with 9.3.

Comment: you problem is not very reproducible, and you're probably out of luck. Your best bet is contacting the postgres mailing list. Your very best bet is restoring form backup and re-migrating your database.

Comment: Data directories are in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.X/name-of-cluster` where X is 3 or 4 and name-of-cluster is `main` by default and other names if you created other clusters. You may check what has been created there exactly and report it in your question.